# Gzip chunked response in play framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

Does anybody know how to compress chunked response on play framework 2.2.1? I have gzipFilter  which perfectly compress regular content, however doesnt compress chunked responses. My code is pretty straightforward, something like this:

```
return ok(new StringChunks() {
    public void onReady(Chunks.Out<String> out) {
        out.write("Huuuge content to be gzipped");
        out.write("Huuuge content2 to be gzipped");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have to Gzip the response before chunking it. If play chunks it, you can't ask Apache to gzip afterwards, nor a play filter.

I got something working with the following code. It's scala but you can get the idea :) (Play 2.2 Scala)

```
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  val enumerator = Enumerator.outputStream { outputStream =>
    val finalOutputStream = {
      if ( canGzip ) new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream)
      else outputStream
    }
    CustomSerializer.serialize(call,finalOutputStream)
  }

  val headers = List(
    Some("Content-Type","application/json"),
    if (canGzip) Some(("Content-Encoding","gzip")) else None
  ).flatten

  Ok.chunked(enumerator).withHeaders(headers: _*)
```